# Overlay window TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY doesn't work as intended

Tags: java, android, overlay, android-permissions, android-windowmanager

I'm trying to create an overlay window using the next code:

```
int OVERLAY_TYPE;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    OVERLAY_TYPE = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
} else {
    OVERLAY_TYPE = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
}

WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

ImageView popupView = new ImageView(this);
popupView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bottom_dialog_background);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        OVERLAY_TYPE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

windowManager.addView(popupView, params);
```

I've added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` to `Manifest` and allowed all needed permissions for that.

It works fine for Android versions up to Android Q. But Q and R versions don't work at the same way. Overlay window creates, persists through some activities and other apps. It even persists through `Android Settings` but when I try to open something deeper than just `Android Settings`, for example `Usage Data Access` screen or `App Data` screen, the Overlay Window disappears. If I press `Back button` it will show the previous Activity and Overlay Window will be shown again.

Does anyone know how to "fix" it and achieve the same behavior for all Android versions?
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get the answer for this ? if so please help have been searching for week but i cant get it to work ;'(

Comment: Have similar issue. Always get `permission denied for window type 2038` when trying to addView() in Foreground Service, on Android 10 and 11. Changing to `TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL` gave another error.

Comment: Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651691/4134215